# What is the best way to subdivide and heat a large room?

Tags: insulation

I live in a large room and would like to subdivide my room, such that it can be heated with a space heater/small mobile radiator.

I live at the end/corner of a large L shaped room, with concrete walls on three sides and a couple of windows. I would like to add a temporary wall on the fourth side, such that it affords me additional privacy and allows for heating.

I currently have a couple of bookshelves and a single sheet dividing my area. Would hanging a plastic tarp or fabric from the ceiling help significantly?

I can't really build a wall from scratch of build anything moderately permanent.

Comment: There are many ways to do it.  Is cost a factor?  Sound dampening?  Security from break-ins?  Ease of assembly?  How do you judge what is *best*?

Comment: Cost is a factor within reason. I don't want to spend more than $100 on materials or labor. Sound dampening isn't a factor, though it is a positive if there is some. This wouldn't really affect security.

I'd judge ease of assembly the most significant factor. I am happy to spend a few hours, but I have very limited and basic skills and experience.

Comment: In the US, $100 for both labor and materials won't get you very far. Even heavy curtains would cost you more than $100.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a situation like this a while ago. I was also under a constraint where I could not make modifications of any kind (no nails, drilling, etc). So here is what I ended up doing.

1. Bought a bunch of C clamps. Since the room had open beam ceiling, I could use the clamps on the beams.
2. Put a clamp on every fourth or fifth beam so that the clamps were approximately 55 apart.
3. Went to a fabric store and bought several yards of the cheapest heavy fabric I could find. I also wanted something half way pleasent in appearance.
4. Cut the fabric in lengths that were the same as the height of the ceiling.
5. String rope (I used steel cable as it could be strong tighter) through the clamps.
6. Loop the ends of each piece of fabric over the rope and fasten the loop closed with safety pins.
7. Now you have a fabric divider for your room. It should keep warm air inside a section of the room.

With this method, you could have multiple layers of fabric for better insulation.